# RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs() throwing ArgumentNullException only in the Windows Azure emulator. Why?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, signalr

I'm using SignalR in an MVC 3.0 Windows Azure application.
The following line throws an `ArgumentNullException` only in the Windows Azure emulator. It doesn't throw if I run the MVC 3.0 application instead of the Cloud application. (I didn't try to run this code in the deployed cloud yet).

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    // ...
}
```

There's no additional information on the error beside the message `Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: instanceName`. I don't know what instance name is it.

I don't have any idea of what might be wrong.
Why would that happen?

**EDIT**

This is the complete exception info:

> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Value cannot be null. Parameter name: instanceName
>   Source=Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core   ParamName=instanceName
>   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.HostDependencyResolverExtensions.InitializeHost(IDependencyResolver
>   resolver, String instanceName, CancellationToken hostShutdownToken)
>          at Owin.OwinExtensions.UseType[T](IAppBuilder builder, Object[] args)
>          at Owin.OwinExtensions.MapHubs(IAppBuilder builder, String path, HubConfiguration configuration)
>          at System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.<>c_*DisplayClass7.b*_5(IAppBuilder
>   map)
>          at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinAppContext.Initialize(Action`1
>   startup)
>          at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.Build(Action`1 startup)
>          at System.Web.Routing.RouteCollectionExtensions.MapOwinPath(RouteCollection
>   routes, String name, String pathBase, Action`1 startup)
>          at System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection
>   routes, String name, String path, HubConfiguration configuration)
>          at System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection
>   routes, String path, HubConfiguration configuration)
>          at System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection
>   routes, HubConfiguration configuration)
>          at System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(RouteCollection
>   routes)
>          at Cerebello.MvcApplication.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in
>   c:\Projetos\Cerebello\Cerebello\CerebelloWebRole\Global.asax.cs:line
>   25
>          at CerebelloWebRole.Code.Helpers.RouteHelper.RegisterAllRoutes() in
>   c:\Projetos\Cerebello\Cerebello\CerebelloWebRole\Code\Helpers\RouteHelper.cs:line
>   82
>          at CerebelloWebRole.WebRole.Run() in c:\Projetos\Cerebello\Cerebello\CerebelloWebRole\WebRole.cs:line 23
>          at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRoleInternal()
>          at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRole()
>          at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.b__2()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

Comment: Can you file a bug on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `MapHubs()` was being called outside the IIS process and it's not allowed now. If you have a method that registers routes and it's shared among code that runs in and outside IIS, you have to make sure that the `MapHubs()` is only called from whithin IIS.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is a known issue: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1616

Please feel free to comment on the issue. It is useful to know that this bug occurs in the Windows Azure Emulator. If you find this issue comes up in deployment, that would also definitely be worth noting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any workaround for me to stop getting this error in the emulator? Btw, I'm gonna test it in the deployment.